# Why am I having networking issues in Utopic?

Tags: networking, xubuntu, 14.10

I upgraded to Utopic yesterday, and ever since I've been encountering errors like these:

- Chrome: `Error code: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG`
- apt-get: `Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]`
- Steam client: `Error Code: -137 Failed to load web page (unknown error).`

I, so far as I know, have made no changes to any network configuration on either my computer or my router.

This issue is particularly odd, since it seems to only affect certain websites. To make it even weirder, if I hit refresh enough, the connection will eventually go through.

Here are some sites I've encountered it on:

- launchpad.net
- store.steampowered.com
- security.ubuntu.com

And some sites where it didn't happen:

- www.ubuntu.com
- steamcommunity.com
- google.com
- askubuntu.com

Not sure if this will help, but here's the output of `ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:8a:5b:62:5c:22  
          inet addr:192.168.8.66  Bcast:192.168.8.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::468a:5bff:fe62:5c22/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:41503 errors:0 dropped:144 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:31957 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:46811931 (46.8 MB)  TX bytes:3473753 (3.4 MB)
          Interrupt:19 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5240 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5240 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:590670 (590.6 KB)  TX bytes:590670 (590.6 KB)
```

Comment: Certainly not everyone. Ubuntu developers used Utopic before release. If this had been broken for everyone, they would have noticed and not released.

It looks like you have an IPv6 related problem, and it only affects IPv6-enabled sites. Is your connection somehow advertising IPv6 support when in fact it doesn't work?

Comment: I don't think it is, unless some update broke my configuration. None of these issues existed for me in 14.04. Was there some sort of change in how networks are/need to be configured?

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed it.

It looks as though my network config got corrupted somehow during the upgrade. There were two extra invalid entries in the list of DNS servers to use. (I have a static internal IP)

After I deleted them, the issue went away.